# How do I display page over category archive in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I've come across the following bit of code to display a page instead of the archive category page. However this code does it for all category pages. How do I specify that it must only replace the category page with ID 1770?

```
add_filter('request', function(array $query_vars) {
    // do nothing in wp-admin
    if(is_admin()) {
        return $query_vars;
    }
    // if the query is for a category
    if(isset($query_vars['category_name'])) {
        // save the slug
        $pagename = $query_vars['category_name'];
        // completely replace the query with a page query
        $query_vars = array('pagename' => "$pagename");
    }
    return $query_vars;
});
```